# combining multiple text files horizontally

Tags: linux, perl

There are multiple tab delimited text files in one directory that contain the same string in the file name: “cnv_data.txt” I would like to combine these files horizontally. This is a part of a Perl script. The number of rows and columns is the same in each file (11 columns and 52 rows). Here is an example of what the desired output would look like:

```
File0ne_cnv_data.txt
 SampleID: sample1
CHROM   POS        FUNC1.gene
chr1    11174372    MTOR


Filetwo_cnv_data.txt
 SampleID: sample2
CHROM   POS        FUNC1.gene
Chr2    1608066     MYCN



Combined_cnv_data.txt                       
SampleID: sample1                   SampleID: sample2       
CHROM   POS       FUNC1.gene        CHROM   POS       FUNC1.gene
chr1    11174372    MTOR            chr1    65310459    JAK1
```

I’ve tried:

```
my $cmd23 = `paste *final_cnv_data.txt >> $combined_CNV`; print $cmd23;
```

and also:

```
my $cmd23 = `cat *final_cnv_data.txt >> $combined_CNV`; print $cmd23;
```

But the final file is blank.

Is there another way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting the `print $cmd23` line to say?

Comment: paste work but each file contains a sample id (first row, first column). when I combine these files the sample ids are displayed right next to each other, even though, files contain multiple columns.

Comment: In your sample output, the 2nd column's data doesn't match at all with the 2nd files data, i.e. `1608066` != `65310459`.  Can you please clarify, or correct your samples? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check paste command

```
paste --help
paste $file1 file2 > $file3
```

Or if you want to combine all files with a sufix you can do

```
paste SUFIX* >> my_new_file.txt
```

EDIT

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 my $cmd23 = `paste /tmp/temp/fichero*`;

 print $cmd23;
```

PD: If you want to print it do not redirect to a file

Comment: The second line looks exactly like what the question already says.

Comment: Yep was just example from man pages, just edited with the snippet for perl. I think is what he/she need, and is important where you put * :D

Comment: Yes, this works with two files but what to do when I don't know how many files there might be. All I know that these files will contain *cnv_data.txt.

Comment: Ok then just do `my $cmd23 = `paste /tmp/temp/*cnv_data.txt`;` it works with multi files too

Comment: Ok, it works well but it pasted sample Id (first column of each file) right next to one other. So row 1, col 1 is is sample_id 1 and row 1, col 2 is sample_id 2, however each file has multiple columns. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: try to use the `column` command for the output: ` my $cmd23 = `paste /tmp/temp/*txt | column -s $\'\t\' -t`;`

Comment: I think only `paste SUFIX* > my_new_file.txt` appends horizontally, `>>` appends vertically.

Comment: > replace the destination file >> append,  but you dont have to do this because you only want to print, do you tried the `column` command?

Comment: I'm adding to a file. `my $cmd23 = `paste $cnv_directory | column -s $\'\t\' -t > $combined_cnv_data;`

Comment: sorry but it didn't work , `my $cmd23 = paste $cnv_directory | column -s $\'\t\' -t > $combined_cnv_data;` All combined date contains double quotes. `"CHROM"`

Comment: ok, figured out a way to cheat the system. :) `my $blank_cell = "";
     my $output_sample_id = "SampleID: ".$sample_id. "\t" .$blank_cell. "\t" .$blank_cell. "\t" .$blank_cell. "\t" .$blank_cell;`

Answer (score 3):

Try as follow.

```
my @ar = <*.txt>; #This is called glob
my %hash;
foreach my $files(@ar)
{
    open my $fh, "<", $files or die "Error opening $!";;
    while (<$fh>)
    {
        chomp;
        $hash{"$."} .= "$_\t";

    }
}
foreach (sort{$a<=>$b}keys %hash)
{
    print "$hash{$_}\n";
}
```

Store the all `.txt` file in an array by using [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

Then, in perl `$.` special variable give the current line number in a file.
Just create the hash, keys are lines number and the values are the line's data.

`.=` This mean concatenation. So just append the next file values at the same line positions.